# How did Tony Stark obtain Thor’s Magic belt (Megingjord)?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017), how did Tony Stark obtain Thor’s Magic belt (Megingjord)? It is mentioned by Happy Hogan when he's reading out the list of things loaded on to the plane they are using to move to new Avengers Facility.

Comment: We don't know...this is just a joke for knowledgable fans.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think it's an easter egg

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: partially.. not all easter eggs are supposedly funny nor every easter egg is targeted only knowledgable fans

Answer (score 3):

The belt is officially known as ***Megingjörð*** , or more commonly referred to as the power belt.

From [ComicBook.com](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/07/07/spider-man-homecoming-thor-magic-belt/),

> In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Happy Hogan plays a significant part as
>   the liaison between Tony and Peter. During one of their numerous
>   conversations, he mentions one of the items that is being sent to the
>   new Avengers HQ, which is referenced as **Thor's Magic Belt**.
>
> It's a one-off mention meant for longtime comic fans, as the belt
>   hasn't been extensively used in recent years. The belt is officially
>   known as Megingjörð, or more commonly referred to as the power belt.
>   It originally debuted in Journey Into Mystery #91 in April 1963 and
>   multiplies Thor's already impressive strength.
>
> While it isn't shown in the film, it's still a nice easter egg for
>   fans

Comment: Ah! It would be awesome if this belt made an appearance in *Avengers 4* to help Thor topple Thanos

Comment: @m1gp0z Thor **did** topple Thanos already isn't he? he did it with Stormbreaker. anyways, we have no source to even assume that this one'll appear anytime soon. and probably we won't see as much as powerful Thanos in sequel, since he used stones and gauntlet seems pretty much broken after the snap

Comment: yes, but it didn't quite "take" - Thanos was able to recover and win in the end

Comment: @m1gp0z Actually, He did. Wasn't 100% success,that's because Thor targeted Thanos' heart. When Thanos kills Heimdall, Thor said *you'd die for this*, and he wanted to prove his word to Thanos, so he needed few minutes to gloat. He targeted Thanos' heart and said *I told you, you;'d die for this*. THor wanted to kill Thanos, and if that was a headshot, then he ma be succeeded.

Answer (score -1):

It's not shown/explained in the movie, it's just an easter egg for the fans.

Comment: Can you include some of the relevant details from link in the answer?

Comment: @NogShine what relevant details? I answered his question...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel - There's a concept of "link rot", where (at some point) that link may no longer point to a valid website.  Therefore, it's common to include important points for anything linked.  This is why Vishwa, who answered 8 hours later than you did, will most likely get more votes; by itself, without any links, it contains all the important information to answer the question.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I just added the link in case anyone wanted more details on the belt, OP's question was asking *Where Stark got the belt* and I answered that. He didn't ask about anything else, so I thought it was not needed to add any more details...Removed the link now to avoid confusion...